# JMenu bar not appearing in GUI

Tags: java

bit of a newbie question but I'm struggling with getting this JMenu bar to appear above the split pane. Could someone please help me out and explain what I did wrong? To my understanding I've added the JMenu and its drop down menu.

Thanks a lot for any solutions and help in understanding with my problem.

the following is my code:

```
public class JavaAssignmentPanel {

    JMenuBar setupMenu() {

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar(); //menubar
        JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("Menu"); //menu
        menuBar.add(menu1); //add menu to gui
        JMenuItem menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("Item 1", KeyEvent.VK_1); //create drop down menu
        menu1.add(menuItem1); //adds drop down menu to gui

        //execute code when selected
        menuItem1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                //  panel.showText("Example1 text - normally read from file");
            }
        });

        return menuBar;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        window window = new window();

    }

    private static class window extends JFrame {

        public window() throws FileNotFoundException {

            JPanel leftScrollPane = new JPanel();
            JPanel rightPane = new JPanel();
            JSplitPane splitPane;

            this.setVisible(true);
            this.setSize(400, 400);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            splitPane = new JSplitPane();
            splitPane.setOrientation(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
            splitPane.setDividerSize(10);
            splitPane.setDividerLocation(100);
            splitPane.setLeftComponent(leftScrollPane);
            splitPane.setRightComponent(rightPane);
            splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
            splitPane.setDividerLocation(200);

            Dimension minimumSize = new Dimension(100, 50);

            leftScrollPane.setSize(400, 400);

            splitPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
            splitPane.setLeftComponent(leftScrollPane);
            splitPane.setRightComponent(rightPane);
            this.add(splitPane);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you never add the menu bar to your window. I don't see that you call `setupMenu()` anywhere.

Comment: JMenuBar setupMenu() { is the first line in the code I provided.

Comment: but that's only the method definition, you never call it

Comment: Have a look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into your code and made the following changes:

*Added a modifiers to setupMenu()*

```
public static JMenuBar setupMenu() { ... }
```

*Added your MenuBar to the JFrame by calling `this.setJMenuBar(setupMenu());` in your JFrames constructor*

I also increased the size of the JFrame to 1280x720 to see the changes.

[**This**](https://pastebin.com/bjxhY4FE) is the class with all changes I made.

I would also encourage you to always name your classes according to the [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), which is in Camel Case, starting with an uppercase letter (Uppper Camel Case). This makes your code easier to read.

Comment: Didn't refresh the page so I didn't see this till now but this actually works perfectly with the splitpane also appearing. Thank you very much.

Ill be also checking the link on the Java Code Conventions as one of my main problems when learning java is finding it difficult to read my code and etc.

Answer (score 1):

So I might just be completely blind, but i can't see you call your setupMenu method anywhere else in the class. You kind of need to tell the program you are adding a menu bar to the jframe...

Comment: @DanielSiwiec yeah, i see that, but you just made a method. You never actually CALLED the method.

Comment: If you dont know what im talking about, go look up a little bit about object oriented java.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `JMenuBar` in the `JFrame`.

See the code, you can do it by making the `setupMenu` method as static and calling it in the window class like this:

```
this.setJMenuBar(setupMenu());
```

Code:

```
public class JavaAssignmentPanel {

// making this method as static
static JMenuBar setupMenu() {

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar(); // menubar
    JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("Menu"); // menu
    menuBar.add(menu1); // add menu to gui
    JMenuItem menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("Item 1", KeyEvent.VK_1); // create
                                                                    // drop
                                                                    // down
                                                                    // menu
    menu1.add(menuItem1); // adds drop down menu to gui

    // execute code when selected
    menuItem1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            // panel.showText("Example1 text - normally read from file");
        }
    });

    return menuBar;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    window window = new window();

}

private static class window extends JFrame {

    public window() throws FileNotFoundException {

        JPanel leftScrollPane = new JPanel();
        JPanel rightPane = new JPanel();
        JSplitPane splitPane;

        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // calling setupMenu method to set the JMenuBar in JFrame
        this.setJMenuBar(setupMenu());

        splitPane = new JSplitPane();
        splitPane.setOrientation(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
        splitPane.setDividerSize(10);
        splitPane.setDividerLocation(100);
        splitPane.setLeftComponent(leftScrollPane);
        splitPane.setRightComponent(rightPane);
        splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
        splitPane.setDividerLocation(200);

        Dimension minimumSize = new Dimension(100, 50);

        leftScrollPane.setSize(400, 400);

        splitPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        splitPane.setLeftComponent(leftScrollPane);
        splitPane.setRightComponent(rightPane);
        this.add(splitPane);

    }
}}
```

Comment: Both of these solutions get the JMenu to finally appear, but weirdly when the JMenu is now working the splitPane stops appearing in the GUI.

Comment: I got it, just write the `this.setVisible(true);` at the end of the window constructor instead of anywhere else, it will start working. It is working on my side with just a little tweak.

Answer (score 1):

You define the method `setupMenu()`, which returns the `JMenuBar`. But that menu bar must be added to the window.

It can be fixed by having

```
this.setJMenuBar(setupMenu());
```

as the last command in your `window()` constructor (that is, after `this.add(splitPane);`.

Comment: Both of these solutions get the JMenu to finally appear, but weirdly when the JMenu is now working the splitPane stops appearing in the GUI.

Comment: try `this.setContentPane(splitPane)` instead of `this.add(splitPane)`.

Comment: Still no luck, the splitPane isn't showing up. Debating on getting rid of the split pane and just using two JPanels but not sure if that would be a better option. What I basically need to get it to do in the long run is when I load a file in with certain values a panel on the left will display the file's text, whereas the panel on the right will need to display a graph.

Comment: Problems all fixed now, I'd like to thank everyone for the help :)